# Why does the cpu responsible for setting the dirty and accessed bits but the OS is responsible for clearing them?

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory

Why does the CPU is usually responsible for setting the dirty and accessed bits but the OS is responsible for clearing them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An access bit couldn't be set by the kernel unless it intercepted *all* memory accesses. That would kind of ruin performance. Same with the dirty bit, it's way easier and simpler and cheaper for the CPU to set it since it's in fact doing the write.

Clearing the dirty bit can't be done by the CPU, because it's part of the paging and swapping, which can only be handled by the OS.